# How can i get selected checkbox value into database?

Tags: javascript, laravel, checkbox

I have a checkbox with foreach data, I want to select 1 or maximum 5 row, and make the rest checkbox be uncheck and that uncheck checkbox can't be sumbitted into the database

This is the form

```xml
<form action="/po_store" method="post">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Tanggal PO</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="tanggal_po" id="datepicker">
          {!! $errors->first('tanggal_po','<span class="text-danger">:message</span>') !!}                                                                                        
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>No Po</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="no_po">
          {!! $errors->first('no_po','<span class="text-danger">:message</span>') !!}                                                            
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Supplier</label>
          <select name="supplier_nama" class="form-control">
            <option value=""hidden>Pilih Supplier</option>
            @foreach ($supplier as $s)
              <option value="{{ $s->nama_supplier }}">{{ $s->nama_supplier }}</option>
            @endforeach
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Apoteker</label>
          <select name="apoteker_nama" class="form-control">
            <option value=""hidden>Pilih Apoteker</option>
            @foreach ($apoteker as $a)
              <option value="{{ $a->nama_apoteker }}">{{ $a->nama_apoteker }}</option>
            @endforeach
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Keterangan</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="keterangan">
        </div>
      </div>
      <form action="{{ route('cari') }}" method="GET">
        <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-top:25px">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-11">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="cari" class="form-control" placeholder="Cari berdasarkan kode dan nama obat ...">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" value="Cari" class="btn btn-primary">
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <tbody>
            <tr class="text-center">
              <th>Pilih</th>
              <td>Kode Obat</td>
              <td>Nama Obat</td>
              <td>Harga Obat</td>
              <td>Jumlah Obat PO</td>
              <td>Total bayar</td>
            </tr>
            @foreach ($obat as $o)
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="select" value="{{ $o->nama_obat }}">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="kode_obat" value="{{ $o->kode_obat }}" readonly>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nama_obat" value="{{ $o->nama_obat }}" readonly>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input id="harga" type="text" class="form-control" name="harga_obat"  value="{{ $o->harga_obat }}" onkeyup="sum()">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input id="jumlah" type="text" class="form-control" name="jumlah" onkeyup="sum()">
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input id="total" type="text" class="form-control" name="total_harga" onkeyup="sum()" readonly>
                </td>
              </tr>
            @endforeach
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success simpan simp-po"><i class="fas fa-check"> Simpan</i></button>                
  </form>
```

This is the javascript to show calculate total field

```
function sum() {
  var harga = document.getElementById('harga').value;
  var jumlah = document.getElementById('jumlah').value;
  var hasil = parseInt(harga)*parseInt(jumlah);
  if(!isNaN(hasil)){
    document.getElementById('total').value = hasil;
  }
}
```

I can't submit the form especially the checkbox because the total field can't be empty. But i want just the selected checkbox get the harga field and can be submit

This is how it's looks like
[image: how the form looks like]

This is my store controller

```
 $message = [
            'required' => '*:attribute harus diisi',
            'numeric' =>'*:attribute harus angka' ,
            'digits_between' => '*:attribute harus berisi 9 atau 13 angka'       
        ];

        $data = $request->validate([
            'tanggal_po' => ['required'],
            'no_po' => ['required'],
            'supplier_nama' => ['required'],
            'apoteker_nama' => ['required'],
            'harga' =>['numeric'],
            'select'=>['required'],
            'jumlah'=>['required'],
            'harga_obat' =>['required'],
            'total_harga'=>['required']
        ],$message);


       $select = $request->select;
       foreach($select as $s){
           $s = $request->select;
       }

        $tanggal_po = $request->input('tanggal_po');
        $no_po = $request->input('no_po');
        $supplier_nama = $request->input('supplier_nama');
        $apoteker_nama = $request->input('apoteker_nama');
        $harga = $request->input('harga');
        $jumlah = $request->input('jumlah');
        $harga_obat = $request->input('harga_obat');
        $total_harga = $request->input('total_harga');

        if(PO::create($request->only($tanggal_po,$no_po,$supplier_nama,$apoteker_nama,$select,$harga,$jumlah,$harga_obat,$total_harga))){
            $request->session()->flash('success', 'Data Berhasil Di Tambahkan');
        }else{
            $request->session()->flash('danger', 'Data Tidak Berhasil Di Tambahkan');
        }
```

Comment: Did you try creating separate form for each row and use js to submit the checked "form"?

Comment: @xxMrPHDxx i did'nt separate the form and using js to submit it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an idea: Your checkboxes and inputs in your row should be declared as an array, e.g. `name[]`:

```html
@foreach ($obat as $o)
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="select[]" value="{{ $o->nama_obat }}">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="kode_obat[]" value="{{ $o->kode_obat }}" readonly>
        </td>
        ...
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Your validation Rule should look like:

```php
$data = $request->validate([
    'kode_obat.*' => 'required_with:select.*,on'
    ...
],$message);
```

In your case i would display all vlidation errors on your form page, to check what's wrong:

```html
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

In your controller handle the checkboxes as follows

```php
$selects = $request->select;
foreach($selects as $select) {
    //do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: i still can't submit my form, i have update my post please check it

Comment: @evvnnxx18 You also have to name the other inputs in your row as array. Best  you dump & die `dd($request)` directly at the beginning of your controller to check what data is being passed.

Comment: @konstantikkoslow it's didn't show anything, it's just reload the page

Comment: @evvnnxx18 I've revised my answer, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

How about to use required_with?

```php
'total_harga'=>['required_with:yourCheckBoxName']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="{{route('admin.post.store')}}"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf

  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="checkbox" id="publish" class="filled-in" name="status" value="1">
  <label for="publish">Publish</label>
  </div>   
  </form>


    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $post = new Post();
        if(isset($request->status))
        {
            $post->status = true;
        }else {
            $post->status = false;
        }
        $post->save();
        Toastr::success('Post Successfully Saved :)','Success');
        return redirect()->route('admin.post.index');
    }
```